# Compare Two Columns To Find Unique Row Keys

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to compare column `A` with `C` and column `B` with`D`, and if any of these pair of comparison don't match I want to create a `data.frame()` that will hold `Key_1` and `Key_2`.

Below is the sample data. Any suggestion on how I can do this quickly with `R` inbuilt packages?

**Input Data Table**

```
data <- read.table(header = TRUE, text= "A  B   Key_1   Key_2   C   D
1   1   A   100 1   1
0.5 0.5 B   101 0.5 0.4
0.5 0.5 C   102 0.4 0.5
1   1   D   103 0.5 2")
```

```
 A   B  Key_1 Key_2   C   D
1.0 1.0   A    100   1.0 1.0
0.5 0.5   B    101   0.5 0.4
0.5 0.5   C    102   0.4 0.5
1.0 1.0   D    103   0.5 2.0
```

**Expected Output**

```
Key_1 Key_2
  B   101
  C   102
  D   103
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
 data[with(data, A != C | B != D), 3:4]

  Key_1 Key_2
2     B   101
3     C   102
4     D   103
```

Or:

```
data[with(data, A != C | B != D), c("Key_1", "Key_2")]
```

Comment: .@tmfmk - Thank you. Sorry I made a mistake in question. It should be `A` compared with `C` and `B` compared with `D`.